# Catchall Routes that mix SSG and SSR

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

So I am working on a project where the base url caters to a few different kind of pages.
Most of these pages are static so I have been using `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` to generate the static pages and serve them.

There are some pages that are also dynamically queries for which I have been using a simple `[base].js` file which uses the above `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` and on fallback, makes a SWR query to fetch data and render on the client side.

So the basic idea is to

- check static file exists and render
- if no static file exists then make a fetch request and see if data is returned and render

I was wondering if there's a way to use `getServerSideProps` in this mix too so that my dynamic queries can be rendered on server side and then SWR can be used only for incremental purposes.

Right now as I add g`etServerSideProps` to the same base file, I end up with `You can not use getStaticProps or getStaticPaths with getServerSideProps. To use SSG, please remove getServerSideProps`

Is it impossible in next to use SSG and SWR together, or is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest thing you can get with Next.js is [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration).

> get the benefits of static (always fast, always online, globally replicated), but with excellent support for dynamic data

Not sure if it entirely fits your requirements.

Comment: Its not ideal but I went ahead with this and made it work. Thanks for the help!